# c# What's the difference between a generic method and a method that takes in objects as parameters?

Tags: c#

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T var1, ref T var2)
{
    T temp = var1;
    var1 = var2;
    var2 = temp;
}

static void Swap2(ref object var1, ref object var2)
{
    object temp = var1;
    var1 = var2;
    var2 = temp;
}
```

I assume that Swap is preferable to Swap2 in some way?

Comment: `Swap` will ensure both parameters have the same type (or base type).

Comment: So Swap2 is actually more flexible?

Comment: Well, if you don't value type-safety or performance - sure, it is more flexible.

Comment: To understand the difference, write some code for both methods (the caller) that tries to swap the values of two strings, and then two ints. You'll notice the code for calling `Swap` is considerably simpler to write.

Comment: For value types, like say, `int`, the value has to boxed and then unboxed when calling the `object` version of the method, but not when calling the generic version. For reference types, there's nothing in this code to ensure both objects are the same or even a compatible type when calling the `object` version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been answered many times so don't be surprised if this get's voted closed.

In your example since the methods are void and they are simply referencing each other there would be no difference.  However; you could filter base types using `Swap<T>` if you added a `where T : {the base type to filter against}`

Generics are usually better than using objects for a variety of reasons but number one should probably be boxing / unboxing. (Which is not happening in your example.)

When you use an `object` you have to cast it to the type expected to use it.  This results in a lot of overhead and potential errors.  When you use generics you have compile time types so you can catch many exceptions before or during compilation, you have stronger types to work with, and most importantly you shouldn't have any boxing / unboxing to deal with (which would reduce performance).

Another thing to consider is that when you use `Swap<T>` in your example you are forcing the two to be the same `Type` since `T` can't be different types at the same time.  With `Swap2` you can re-reference any two objects; however you're going to have to manually convert those types to object and they can't go back to their original type because unless the two are of the same type to begin with.

Remember `ref` parameters do not benefit from polymorphism.
`T` parameters are generic but since we only have one `T` the types will always be the same.

```
using System;

namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = "Hey There";
            var employer1 = new Employer() { Name = "Microsoft" };
            var employer2 = new Employer() { Name = "EA Games" };

            //Generic Swap
            SwapGeneric(ref employer1, ref employer2);
            //Swap(ref text, ref employee2); //<- compiler error. Cannot be inferred by the usage.

            Console.WriteLine("Types of the same swapped");
            Console.WriteLine(employer1.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(employer2.Name);
            Console.WriteLine();
            //object Swap
            //SwapObject(ref employee1, ref employee2); //- compiler error.  Cannot convert to ref object.

            //Reference string and employer as object.
            var textObject = text as object;
            var employerObject = employer1 as object;

            SwapObject(ref textObject, ref employerObject);

            //Existing types cannot be re-referenced.
            //text = (Employer)textObject; //<-compiler error.  Cannot implicitly convert...
            //employer1 = (string)employerObject; //<-compiler error. Cannot implicitly convert....

            //We can cast objects to swapped types succesfully but see how easily this can cause error and confusion.
            Console.WriteLine("Objects of different types swapped");
            Console.WriteLine(((Employer)textObject).Name);
            Console.WriteLine((string)employerObject);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SwapGeneric<T>(ref T var1, ref T var2)
        {
            T temp = var1;
            var1 = var2;
            var2 = temp;
        }

        static void SwapObject(ref object var1, ref object var2)
        {
            object temp = var1;
            var1 = var2;
            var2 = temp;
        }
    }

    public class Employer
    {
        public object Name { get; set; }
    }
}
//OUTPUT
//Types Swapped
//EA Games
//Microsoft

//Objects Swapped
//EA Games
//Hey There
```